# Intermittent no submission processing for buttons and links

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket

My Apache Wicket web application is deployed on Google App Engine for Java (GAE/J).

I have a problem (for about 1-5% of click events) for this app where, after a link or button has been clicked, instead of the relevant component's and form's `onSubmit()` methods being processed, the same original page is presented to the user as if a browser page refresh had been commanded instead.

**Sample rendered HTML mark-up**

```
<a href="../wicket/page?20-1.ILinkListener-lnkLogOn" tabindex="2001">Log on</a>

<button type="submit" tabindex="3" name="btnLogOn" id="id2d">
 Log on
</button>
```

A possibly related issue is that sometimes flash messages either do not appear when then should, or else appear but are empty.

These problems might be caused by a failure to interpret the user's web session properly.

I get the feeling that request/response cycles are not being processed properly, and that the processing of requests is faulty with their session ID not being used properly and the request not being passed to an existing app instance ready to process.

Has anyone else encountered this problem with applications that have previously run without issue?

**Software environment**

- Wicket: 1.5.7
- GAE/J:  1.7.0
- Java:   1.6.0_34

Comment: Did you modify your wicket application for GAE (as described [here](https://wicket-stuff.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/wicket-stuff/trunk/wicketstuff-core/jdk-1.5-parent/gae-initializer-parent/))?

Comment: @Nicktar: I had already set my application to work with GAE/J with similar things to those done by the WicketStuff in your link (and additional things too). Out of interest:  1. I could not find `WicketObjects.setObjectStreamFactory(...)` (but I set my own serialiser instead).  2. I could not find `application.getResourceSettings().setFileUploadCleaner(...)` (but I use my own `FileItem`s instead).  3.  I could not find `new PersistentPageManager(...)` (but I use my own `DefaultPageManagerProvider.get(...)` instead).